# In an multi-tenant enviroment how can I provide different metadata for different Service Providers at runtime on different urls (subdomains)?

Tags: java, single-sign-on, spring-saml, shibboleth, service-provider

Working on SP initiated Single Sign On (SSO) with both SP and IdP are self-hosted thus have flexibility of editing both. I am using spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.1.RELEASE for hosting spring application (spring-security-3.2.8, spring-mvc-3.2.14.RELEASE), which serves multiple tenants at urls say:
 **sp1.example.org**,
 **sp2.example.org** 
IdP is hosted using Shibboleth IdPv3.2.1 which is working fine with multiple applications hosted on different SP servers.

I am trying to send different metadata from the same server for sp1 & sp2. I read an about multi-tenant SP [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28056206/how-do-i-automatically-pick-the-configured-saml-identity-provider-in-a-multi-ten) and [here](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/saml/127716-idp-initiated-saml-sign-on-with-multi-tenant-sp-configuration) custom logic by overriding SAMLContextProviderImpl `populatePeerEntityId`, similarly I am trying to override `populateLocalEntityId` because I can't use `alias`.

**Can someone give an example code for Overriding `populateLocalEntityId` for handling multi-tenants metadata ?**

SP configuration is as shown below:

```
<!-- Filters for processing of SAML messages -->
<beans:bean id="samlFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
    <filter-chain-map request-matcher="ant">
        <filter-chain pattern="/saml/login/**" filters="samlEntryPoint" />
        <filter-chain pattern="/saml/logout/**" filters="samlLogoutFilter" />
        <filter-chain pattern="/saml/metadata/**" filters="metadataDisplayFilter" />
        <filter-chain pattern="/saml/SSO/**" filters="samlWebSSOProcessingFilter" />
        <filter-chain pattern="/saml/SSOHoK/**" filters="samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter" />
        <filter-chain pattern="/saml/SingleLogout/**" filters="samlLogoutProcessingFilter" />
        <filter-chain pattern="/saml/discovery/**" filters="samlIDPDiscovery" />
    </filter-chain-map>
</beans:bean>

<!-- Handler deciding where to redirect user after successful login -->
<beans:bean id="successRedirectHandler" class="com.example.web.sso.CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler" ></beans:bean>
<!-- <beans:bean id="successRedirectHandler" 
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
   <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/WEB-INF/security/idpSelection.jsp"/>
</beans:bean>  --> 


<!-- Use the following for interpreting RelayState coming from unsolicited 
    response as redirect URL: 
    <beans:bean id="successRedirectHandler" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLRelayStateSuccessHandler"> 
    <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/" /> </beans:bean> -->

<!-- Handler deciding where to redirect user after failed login -->
<beans:bean id="failureRedirectHandler" class="com.example.web.sso.CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler"></beans:bean>

<!-- <beans:bean id="failureRedirectHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
    <property name="useForward" value="true" />
    <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/error.jsp" />
</beans:bean>  -->

<!-- Handler for successful logout -->
<beans:bean id="successLogoutHandler"
    class="com.example.web.sso.CustomLogoutSuccessHandler" ></beans:bean>
<!-- <beans:bean id="successLogoutHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler">
    <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/logout.jsp" />
</beans:bean> -->

<authentication-manager alias="samlauthenticationManager">
    <!-- Register authentication manager for SAML provider -->
    <authentication-provider ref="samlAuthenticationProvider" />
    <!-- Register authentication manager for administration UI -->
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service id="adminInterfaceService">
            <user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<!-- Logger for SAML messages and events -->
<beans:bean id="samlLogger" class="org.springframework.security.saml.log.SAMLDefaultLogger" >
    <beans:property name="logMessages" value="true" />
    <beans:property name="logErrors" value="true" />
</beans:bean>

<!-- Central storage of cryptographic keys -->
<beans:bean id="keyManager" class="org.springframework.security.saml.key.JKSKeyManager">

    <beans:constructor-arg value="/WEB-INF/keys/samlKeystore.jks"></beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="nalle123" />
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:map>
            <beans:entry key="apollo" value="nalle123" />
        </beans:map>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="apollo" />
</beans:bean>

<!-- Entry point to initialize authentication, default values taken from 
    properties file -->
<beans:bean id="samlEntryPoint" class="com.example.web.sso.CustomSAMLEntryPoint">
    <beans:property name="defaultProfileOptions">
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileOptions">
            <beans:property name="binding" value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"/>
            <beans:property name="nameID" value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress" />
            <beans:property name="includeScoping" value="false" />
            <beans:property name="forceAuthN" value="false" />
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<!-- IDP Discovery Service -->
<beans:bean id="samlIDPDiscovery" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLDiscovery">
    <beans:property name="idpSelectionPath" value="/WEB-INF/security/idpSelection.jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<!-- Filter automatically generates default SP metadata --> 
<beans:bean id="metadataGeneratorFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter">
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator">
            <beans:property name="entityId" value="com:example:namespaceId:saml:poc" />
            <!-- <beans:property name="entityBaseURL" value="https://sp1.example.com:8080/" /> -->
            <beans:property name="requestSigned" value="true" />
            <beans:property name="wantAssertionSigned" value="true" />
            <beans:property name="extendedMetadata">
                <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                    <beans:property name="idpDiscoveryEnabled" value="true" />
                </beans:bean>
            </beans:property>
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="metadataGenerator" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator">
            <beans:property name="entityId" value="com:example:namespaceId:saml:poc" />
            <beans:property name="entityBaseURL" value="https://sp1.example.com:8080/" />
            <beans:property name="requestSigned" value="true" />
            <beans:property name="wantAssertionSigned" value="true" />
            <beans:property name="extendedMetadata">
                <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                    <beans:property name="idpDiscoveryEnabled" value="true" />
                </beans:bean>
            </beans:property>
        </beans:bean>

<!-- The filter is waiting for connections on URL suffixed with filterSuffix 
    and presents SP metadata there -->
<beans:bean id="metadataDisplayFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataDisplayFilter" />

<!-- Configure HTTP Client to accept certificates from the keystore for 
    HTTPS verification -->
<!-- <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.trust.httpclient.TLSProtocolConfigurer"> 
    <beans:property name="sslHostnameVerification" value="default"/> </beans:bean> -->

<!-- IDP Metadata configuration - paths to metadata of IDPs in circle of 
    trust is here -->
<beans:bean id="metadata"
    class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CachingMetadataManager">
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:list>
            <!-- Example of classpath metadata with Extended Metadata -->
            <beans:bean
                class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
                <beans:constructor-arg>
                    <beans:bean
                        class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.ResourceBackedMetadataProvider">
                        <beans:constructor-arg>
                            <beans:bean class="java.util.Timer" />
                        </beans:constructor-arg>
                        <beans:constructor-arg>
                            <beans:bean class="org.opensaml.util.resource.ClasspathResource">
                            <!-- <beans:bean class="org.opensaml.util.resource.FilesystemResource"> -->
                                    <beans:constructor-arg value = "/WEB-INF/metadata/sp1-mymetadata.xml"></beans:constructor-arg>
                            </beans:bean>
                        </beans:constructor-arg>
                        <beans:property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool" />
                    </beans:bean>
                </beans:constructor-arg>
                <beans:constructor-arg>

                    <beans:bean
                        class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                        <beans:property name="local" value="true" />
                        <beans:property name="securityProfile" value="metaiop" />
                        <beans:property name="sslSecurityProfile" value="pkix" />
                        <beans:property name="sslHostnameVerification" value="default" />
                        <!-- <beans:property name="sslHostnameVerification" value="allowAll" /> -->
                        <beans:property name="signMetadata" value="false" />
                        <beans:property name="signingKey" value="apollo" />
                        <beans:property name="encryptionKey" value="apollo" />
                        <beans:property name="requireArtifactResolveSigned" value="false" />
                        <beans:property name="requireLogoutRequestSigned" value="false" />
                        <beans:property name="requireLogoutResponseSigned" value="false" />
                        <beans:property name="idpDiscoveryEnabled" value="false" />
                        <beans:property name="idpDiscoveryURL" value="https://sp1.example.com/saml/discovery" />
                        <beans:property name="idpDiscoveryResponseURL" value="https://sp1.example.com/saml/login?disco=true" />
                    </beans:bean>
                </beans:constructor-arg>

            </beans:bean>
            <!-- Example of HTTP metadata without Extended Metadata -->
            <!-- <beans:bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider">
                URL containing the metadata
                <beans:constructor-arg>
                    <beans:value type="java.lang.String">https://idp.ssocircle.com/idp-meta.xml</beans:value>
                    <beans:value type="java.lang.String">https://sp1.example.com/idp-meta.xml</beans:value>
                </beans:constructor-arg>
                Timeout for metadata loading in ms
                <beans:constructor-arg>
                    <beans:value type="int">15000</beans:value>
                </beans:constructor-arg>
                <beans:property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool" />
            </beans:bean> -->

            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
                <beans:constructor-arg>
                    <beans:bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.FilesystemMetadataProvider">
                        <beans:constructor-arg>
                            <beans:value type="java.io.File">/shared/saml/idp-metadata-exampleIdp.xml</beans:value>
                        </beans:constructor-arg>
                        <beans:property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
                    </beans:bean>
                </beans:constructor-arg>
                <beans:constructor-arg>
                    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata"/>
                </beans:constructor-arg>
            </beans:bean>

            <!-- Example of file system metadata without Extended Metadata -->
            <!-- <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.FilesystemMetadataProvider"> 
                <constructor-arg> <value type="java.io.File">/usr/local/metadata/idp.xml</value> 
                </constructor-arg> <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/> </bean> -->
        </beans:list>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
    <!-- OPTIONAL used when one of the metadata files contains information 
        about this service provider -->
    <!-- <property name="hostedSPName" value=""/> -->
    <!-- OPTIONAL property: can tell the system which IDP should be used for 
        authenticating user by default. -->
    <!-- <property name="defaultIDP" value="http://localhost:8080/opensso"/> -->
    <beans:property name="defaultIDP" value="https://login.example.com/idp/shibboleth"/>
</beans:bean>

<!-- SAML Authentication Provider responsible for validating of received 
    SAML messages -->
<beans:bean id="samlAuthenticationProvider"
    class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider">
    <!-- OPTIONAL property: can be used to store/load user data after login -->
    <beans:property name="userDetails" ref="sAMLUserDetailsServiceImpl" />
    <beans:property name="forcePrincipalAsString" value="false" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="sAMLUserDetailsServiceImpl"
    class="com.example.service.impl.SAMLUserDetailsServiceImpl"></beans:bean>

<!-- Provider of default SAML Context -->
<!-- <beans:bean id="contextProvider"
    class="org.springframework.security.saml.context.SAMLContextProviderImpl"> -->
<beans:bean id="contextProvider"
    class="com.example.service.impl.CustomSAMLContextProviderImpl"> 
    <beans:property name="storageFactory">
        <!-- <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.storage.EmptyStorageFactory" /> -->
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.storage.HttpSessionStorageFactory" />
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<!-- <beans:bean id="contextProvider"
    class="org.springframework.security.saml.context.SAMLContextProviderLB">
    <beans:property name="scheme" value="https" />
    <beans:property name="serverName" value="https://sp1.example.com" />
    <beans:property name="serverPort" value="443" />
    <beans:property name="includeServerPortInRequestURL" value="false" />
</beans:bean>  -->

<!-- Processing filter for WebSSO profile messages -->
<beans:bean id="samlWebSSOProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter">
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="samlauthenticationManager" />
    <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="successRedirectHandler" />
    <beans:property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="failureRedirectHandler" />
    <beans:property name="sessionAuthenticationStrategy" ref="sas"/>
</beans:bean>

<!-- Processing filter for WebSSO Holder-of-Key profile -->
<beans:bean id="samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter">
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="samlauthenticationManager" />
    <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="successRedirectHandler" />
    <beans:property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="failureRedirectHandler" />
</beans:bean>

<!-- Logout handler terminating local session -->
<beans:bean id="logoutHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler">
    <beans:property name="invalidateHttpSession" value="true" />
</beans:bean>

<!-- Override default logout processing filter with the one processing SAML 
    messages -->
<beans:bean id="samlLogoutFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutFilter">
    <beans:constructor-arg index="0" ref="successLogoutHandler" />
    <beans:constructor-arg index="1" ref="logoutHandler" />
    <beans:constructor-arg index="2" ref="logoutHandler" />
</beans:bean>

<!-- Filter processing incoming logout messages -->
<!-- First argument determines URL user will be redirected to after successful 
    global logout -->
<beans:bean id="samlLogoutProcessingFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter">
    <beans:constructor-arg index="0" ref="successLogoutHandler" />
    <beans:constructor-arg index="1" ref="logoutHandler" />
</beans:bean>

<!-- Class loading incoming SAML messages from httpRequest stream -->
<beans:bean id="processor"
    class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl">
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:list>
            <beans:ref bean="postBinding" />
            <beans:ref bean="redirectBinding" />
            <beans:ref bean="artifactBinding" />
            <beans:ref bean="soapBinding" />
            <beans:ref bean="paosBinding" />
        </beans:list>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>

<!-- SAML 2.0 WebSSO Assertion Consumer -->
<beans:bean id="webSSOprofileConsumer"
    class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl" >
    <!-- maximum lifetime of assertion issued by Idp default 3000-->
    <!-- <beans:property name="maxAssertionTime" value="300"></beans:property>  -->
    <!-- maximum lifetime of authentication issued default 7200-->
    <!-- <beans:property name="maxAssertionTime" value="300"></beans:property>  -->
</beans:bean>

<!-- SAML 2.0 Holder-of-Key WebSSO Assertion Consumer -->
<beans:bean id="hokWebSSOprofileConsumer"
    class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl" />

<!-- SAML 2.0 Web SSO profile -->
<beans:bean id="webSSOprofile"
    class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileImpl" />

<!-- SAML 2.0 Holder-of-Key Web SSO profile -->
<beans:bean id="hokWebSSOProfile"
    class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl" />

<!-- SAML 2.0 ECP profile -->
<beans:bean id="ecpprofile"
    class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileECPImpl" />

<!-- SAML 2.0 Logout Profile -->
<beans:bean id="logoutprofile"
    class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.SingleLogoutProfileImpl" />

<!-- Bindings, encoders and decoders used for creating and parsing messages -->
<beans:bean id="postBinding"
    class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPPostBinding">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="parserPool" />
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="velocityEngine" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="redirectBinding"
    class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPRedirectDeflateBinding">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="parserPool" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="artifactBinding"
    class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPArtifactBinding">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="parserPool" />
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="velocityEngine" />
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.ArtifactResolutionProfileImpl">
            <beans:constructor-arg>
                <beans:bean class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient">
                    <beans:constructor-arg>
                        <beans:bean
                            class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager" />
                    </beans:constructor-arg>
                </beans:bean>
            </beans:constructor-arg>
            <beans:property name="processor">
                <beans:bean
                    class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl">
                    <beans:constructor-arg ref="soapBinding" />
                </beans:bean>
            </beans:property>
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="soapBinding"
    class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPSOAP11Binding">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="parserPool" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="paosBinding"
    class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPPAOS11Binding">
    <beans:constructor-arg ref="parserPool" />
</beans:bean>

<!-- Initialization of OpenSAML library -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLBootstrap" />

<!-- Initialization of the velocity engine -->
<beans:bean id="velocityEngine" class="org.springframework.security.saml.util.VelocityFactory"
    factory-method="getEngine" />

<!-- XML parser pool needed for OpenSAML parsing -->
<beans:bean id="parserPool" class="org.opensaml.xml.parse.StaticBasicParserPool"
    init-method="initialize">
    <beans:property name="builderFeatures">
        <beans:map>
            <beans:entry key="http://apache.org/xml/features/dom/defer-node-expansion"
                value="false" />
        </beans:map>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="parserPoolHolder"
    class="org.springframework.security.saml.parser.ParserPoolHolder" ></beans:bean>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update 1: A better solution is to extend SAMLContextProviderImpl and Override populateLocalEntityId, getLocalEntity, getLocalAndPeerEntity to set proper SAMLMessageContext as new SAMLMessageContext is created for each request.

```
@Override
public SAMLMessageContext getLocalAndPeerEntity(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws MetadataProviderException {

        SAMLMessageContext context = new SAMLMessageContext();
        populateGenericContext(request, response, context);
        //changed to send URL instead of URI
        populateLocalEntityId(context, request.getRequestURL().toString());
        populateLocalContext(context);
        populatePeerEntityId(context);
        populatePeerContext(context);
        return context;

}

@Override
public SAMLMessageContext getLocalEntity(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws MetadataProviderException {

        SAMLMessageContext context = new SAMLMessageContext();
        populateGenericContext(request, response, context);
        populateLocalEntityId(context, request.getRequestURL().toString());
        populateLocalContext(context);
        return context;

}

    @Override
    protected void populateLocalEntityId(SAMLMessageContext context, String requestURL) throws MetadataProviderException {

            String entityId;
            HTTPInTransport inTransport = (HTTPInTransport) context.getInboundMessageTransport();

            // Pre-configured entity Id
            entityId = (String) inTransport.getAttribute(org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLConstants.LOCAL_ENTITY_ID);
            if (entityId != null) {
                    // same code as super class

            } else { // Defaults    
               //Now setting proper entityId as required
               //in this case https://sp1.wooqer.com/sp
               if(org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.ordinalIndexOf(requestURL, "/", 3) != -1) {
                        context.setLocalEntityId(requestURL.substring(0, org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.ordinalIndexOf(requestURL, "/", 3)).concat("/sp"));
                } else {
                        context.setLocalEntityId(requestURL.concat("/sp"));
                }
                context.setLocalEntityRole(SPSSODescriptor.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME);
            }
    }
```

Setting hostedSPName in MetadataGeneratorFilter is not a good solution as the @Autowired MetadataManager has to be set under a synchronized block so as to ensure multiple requests don't overwrite values. The MetadataManager is still can be used outside filter where we cannot be sure of its state.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
**This can be done by creating a federation of all SPs (subdomains running under one application in this case) and then selecting the appropriate entityID & thus metadata at runtime.**

I did the following steps to handle this issue. So first create a metadata for federation and add all subdomains (SPs) running on this one application in one federation:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EntitiesDescriptor xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:shibmd="urn:mace:shibboleth:metadata:1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Name="https://example-federation.org/metadata/example-federation-name.xml">
   <md:EntityDescriptor xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" xmlns:mdui="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:metadata:ui" ID="org_example_shagunakarsh_saml_poc_sp1" entityID="org:example:shagunakarsh:saml:poc:sp1">
      <!--other params-->
      ......
   </md:EntityDescriptor>
   <md:EntityDescriptor xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" ID="org_example_shagunakarsh_saml_poc_sp2" entityID="org:example:shagunakarsh:saml:poc:sp2">
      <!--other params-->
      ......
   </md:EntityDescriptor>
</EntitiesDescriptor>
```

Now we need to specify this metadata file in your **metadata bean** in security-applicationContext.xml:

```
<beans:bean id="metadata"
class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CachingMetadataManager">
    .... 
    <beans:constructor-arg value = "/path/to/metadata/federation-mymetadata.xml"></beans:constructor-arg>
```

(Read Update 1, overriding filter for this purpose is not recommended) Now we need to select the appropriate metadata at runtime using the accessed URL, which can be achieved by extending MetadataGeneratorFilter and overriding processMetadataInitialization function:

```
    @Override
    protected void processMetadataInitialization(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException {

                    // In case the hosted SP metadata weren't initialized, let's do it now
                    if (manager.getHostedSPName() == null) {

                        synchronized (MetadataManager.class) {
                              //same code as Base Class
                        }

                    } else {
                            // if known SP is found from federation metadata
                            String requestURL = request.getRequestURL().toString();
                            String subDomain = requestURL.substring(requestURL.indexOf("//") + 2, requestURL.indexOf("."));
                            //set proper SP entityID
                            manager.setHostedSPName("org:example:shagunakarsh:saml:poc:" + subDomain);
                    }
            }
```

Then update the security-applicationContext.xml with this CustomMetadataGeneratorFilter:

```
<beans:bean id="metadataGeneratorFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CustomMetadataGeneratorFilter">
```

Also don't forget to update the metadata in your IdP (this case Shibboleth IDPv3). Redeploy both IdP and SP and it should work.